# Close APP Using Jquery Mobile in Blackberry

Tags: jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile

i have an app in Blackberry, I was Build in using Jquery Mobile, but i have some problem, i want to close app using a button with Jquery Mobile command, here is currently my code

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="exit" data-icon="delete">Exit</a></li>
</ul>
```

i have add feature in config.xml

```
<feature id="blackberry.system" ... ></feature>
```

and some Jquery Event

```
$function({
     $("#id").click(function(){
        device.exitApp();
     });
});
```

but it won't work att all, have i Miss something ? or the code is 100% wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `app Feature` to have access to the Application API Methods

`<feature id="blackberry.app" />`

**Then you can exit the app with :**

```
$function({
     $("#id").click(function(){
        blackberry.app.exit()
     });
})
```

[**See Documentation/API Reference**](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.app.html)

Comment: thanks @Richard A, I have try that one, it seems doesn't work :( have any idea ? i'm using Blackberry Simulator OS 6.

Comment: In the docs, it says the supported platforms are:
 - BlackBerry OS 5.0+ 
 - BlackBerry PlayBook 1.0+ 
 - Ripple Emulator. That my be the cause.. Try downloading ripple :)

Comment: at last it works :) the problem is the id on the button, it can not be exit, must be some thing else